# Matrix Powers A^k - Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors - Chapter 6 Gilbert Strang

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I confused about the formula below:

It's different from his lecture note. Why it's different? It doesn't matter the order?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The second one in his lecture [notes](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-06sc-linear-algebra-fall-2011/least-squares-determinants-and-eigenvalues/diagonalization-and-powers-of-a/MIT18_06SCF11_Ses2.9sum.pdf) must be a typo; it should be $S\Lambda^kc$. In general, $S\Lambda^k= \Lambda^kS$ is not true.

Here is a counterexample:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1&2\\3&4
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1&0\\0&2
\end{pmatrix}
\ne
\begin{pmatrix}
1&0\\0&2
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1&2\\3&4
\end{pmatrix}
$$